# MYSQL Ignore Repeat Values and Get Unique Count

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, unique

Basically, as the question states, I am looking for the easiest and most straight forward way of getting counts based on unique values.

Here is my data set:

```
id   |    item_id   |   user_id
1    |    10        |   123
2    |    10        |   123
3    |    10        |   123
4    |    11        |   123
5    |    12        |   123
6    |    10        |   456
7    |    10        |   789
8    |    12        |   456
```

Ideally, when I run the query I should get the following:

```
count    |    user_id
3        |    123
2        |    456
1        |    789
```

Where even though user 123 has 5 items to their name, the really only purchased 3 unique items.  Is this really straight forward and I'm just missing it completely?  Here is what I have currently:

```
SELECT count(user_id) AS count, item_id, user_id
FROM table
GROUP BY item_id, user_id
HAVING count > 1
ORDER BY count DESC
```

This is producing the opposite of what I want:

```
count    |    user_id
5        |    123
2        |    456
1        |    789
```

Thanks in advance!  And if this has been answered already, please point me in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count distinct item ids and then group by the user id:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) AS count, 
  user_id
FROM 
  event_assigned
GROUP BY 
  user_id
ORDER BY 
  count DESC
```